# Vue component define some of the props as data type, leave others as-is

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I really like the syntax `props: ['title', 'someInt', 'description']` in my Vue component. How do I require just 1 of those props, namely `someInt`, to be an integer? But without having to explicitly define the data types for the other props (they can remain default as String).

My parent component is doing `<my-component title='some title' some-int='100' description='desc'></my-component>` and later when I do `this.someInt` it's of datatype String not integer (Number). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the `props: ['title', 'someInt', 'description']` syntax if you updated your `<my-component` to use binding for the properties you want as Numbers. Example:

`<my-component title='some title' :some-int='100' description='desc'></my-component>` - that will make `someInt` come thorugh as a Number since you're binding it via the `:` character. Vue parses the expression literally.

Comment: nice question and a good solution. Did you consider using `slots` anyway?